# Getting error with django-taggit with admin

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

In a Django project I installed django_taggit. I'm getting this error when I syncdb my project.

```
AttributeError: 'TaggableManager' object has no attribute 'related'
```

My models.py something like this...

```
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tags = TaggableManager()
```

and admin.py something like this...

```
from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.register(Post)
```

Answer (score 1):

Django admin is trying to use the TaggableManager to manage your post objects. You need to be careful when using custom managers; as [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#modifying-initial-manager-querysets) specify:

> If you use custom Manager objects, take note that the first Manager Django encounters (in the order in which they’re defined in the model) has a special status. Django interprets the first Manager defined in a class as the “default” Manager, and several parts of Django (including dumpdata) will use that Manager exclusively for that model. As a result, it’s a good idea to be careful in your choice of default manager in order to avoid a situation where overriding get_query_set() results in an inability to retrieve objects you’d like to work with.

An easy way to get around this is to manually specify `Post.objects` first:

```python
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    objects = models.Manager()
    tags = TaggableManager()
```

Comment: Could you post the full stack trace?

Comment: Sorry, there is no stack trace. I was following a tutorial from youtube named "Building a blog in 30 mins with Django (Screencast HD)" with Django1.6(from github). That video was targeted Django1.3. Maybe there is version mismatch problem.

Comment: I mean, when you get the AttributeError you should probably also get a lot of other information. Could you post all of that information?